# Ubuntu very slow boot after chaning driver (Nvidia)

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I previously used X.Org driver for my Ubuntu desktop, and my graphic card is  Nvidia GTX 1070, actually I've never been satisfied with my boot time because I use an high-end SSD and the boot time always takes more than 20 s (comparing to my Ubuntu laptop which is Radeon graphics and the same SSD, only takes 9 s).

However, recently I met some problem with compatibility issue of RStudio (always crashed) and I had to change to Nvdia driver as it was described [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/242045/HOW-TO-GET-THE-LATEST-NVIDIA-AMD-OR-INTEL-GRAPHICS-DRIVERS-ON-UBUNTU/). So the Rstudio no longer crashes, however I face a very slow boot, after entering the grub (I have dual-boot), it freezes about 30s, and then the PC has a very transient beep (shorter than the boot one), and then I had to wait another 30 s until I can enter the login.

If I run `systemd-analyze`, it shows:

```
Startup finished in 6.560s (firmware) + 6.560s (loader) + 2.848s (kernel) + 38.816s (userspace) = 54.786s
graphical.target reached after 38.725s in userspace
```

Does any one know how to solve this issue?

Comment: I dont want to sound to definitive here, but it sounds like you may be waiting on something to time out. Try to follow the instructions [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelBoot) which will allow to view your boot in verbose mode. I wouldnt be surprised if it turned out there was a network module or something that was actually causing the issue. If that is the case, then you will have two options: fix the error or reduce the timeout period (from like 30s to 5 or 10). Try that and report back what you see.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I quite didn't understand the instruction here, so I just removed  the "quiet splash" inside the /etc/default/grub, and I have seen the frozen (+10s) one is the "starting socket activation for snappy daemon"... I am now trying to find what does this mean.

Comment: I finally sort it out, Please see my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reseach I think I finally solved this problem, since seems like my RStudio wasn't performing properly with X.Org,so basically in the "Software & Update" > "Additional Drivers" changed to Nvidia-driver-390 (proprietary) as I used to think this is more "reliable", then I had several other problems with crashing nautilus, slow boot, etc. So then I went ot Nvidia [website](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) to check which is the proper driver, and it shows the nvidia-driver-410 (open source), once I changed to that driver, up to now I don't see any issue.