# Ubuntu 18.04 random small freezes

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, freeze

Just reinstalled my computer with ubuntu 18.04. After installation I keep getting these random freezes lasting 0.5 to 1 seconds, during the freeze everything on the computer stops, the cursor gets stuck and if I am typing it repeats the key until the freeze stops.

The pc has the following specs: https://www.excaliberpc.com/689344/msi-p65-creator-8re-020-sliver.html

I am running with the 430.26 NVIDIA driver

Any help or nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, since this is incredibly annoying having to work with.

Comment: have you checked that you have the right driver?
https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

Comment: I installed the driver through the automated ubuntu driver installer.

Comment: I am super scared of using anything else, last time I spend 12+ hours juggling nvidia drivers it ended with me having to reinstall everything since nothing worked.

Comment: I experiences similar situation, until I figure out that I used the wrong driver. So I highly recommend you check if you use the right one. This page offers downloadable driver and Is easy to install. Alternatively, once you know the right driver, check "additionak driver" in " update" and choose the right one.

Comment: This Is my original post.   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1151112/ubuntu-very-slow-boot-after-chaning-driver-nvidia?noredirect=1#comment1913665_1151112

Comment: If an answer to a previously posted question could help here, it would be better to [flag](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) this question as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: following that post I updated to Driver Version: 430.26, the problem still persists

Comment: I do not have the same problem as mentioned by Kuai, my freezes are only brief and stops again, but they are very frequent...

Comment: Can you open the terminal (shortcut) during the freeze?

Comment: it lasts 0.5-1 seconds and I can do absolutely nothing